# How to Create a table on variable name in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
WHILE @i < @deptcount + 1 
  BEGIN 
      --creating dynamic tables   
      DECLARE @tablenames NVARCHAR(50) 

      SET @tablenames = 'dept' + Cast(@i AS NVARCHAR) 

      EXECUTE ('create table '+@tablenames+ 
      ' (deptno int, formno int, stdpr int, agg int)') 

      SET @i = @i + 1 
  END
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables (like in the `CAST`) and parameters that you use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0, @deptcount INT = 4;

while @i < @deptcount+1
Begin 
  --creating dynamic tables 
  declare @tablenames nvarchar(50)
  set @tablenames = '##dept'+CAST(@i as nvarchar)
  execute('create table '+@tablenames+' (deptno int, formno int, stdpr int, agg int)')
  set @i = @i +1
End

SELECT *
FROM ##dept1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM ##dept2
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM ##dept3;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/387214)**</kbd>

But reconsider your approach:

> [**CREATE TABLE @tbl**](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Cre_tbl)
>
> The desire here is to create a table of which the name is determined
>   at run-time.
>
> If we just look at the arguments against using dynamic SQL in stored
>   procedures, few of them are really applicable here. If a stored
>   procedure has a static CREATE TABLE in it, the user who runs the
>   procedure must have permissions to create tables, so dynamic SQL will
>   not change anything. Plan caching obviously has nothing to do with it.
>   Etc.
>
> Nevertheless: Why? Why would you want to do this? **If you are creating
>   tables on the fly in your application, you have missed some
>   fundamentals about database design. In a relational database, the set
>   of tables and columns are supposed to be constant. They may change
>   with the installation of new versions, but not during run-time.**
>
> Sometimes when people are doing this, it appears that they want to
>   construct unique names for temporary tables. This is completely
>   unnecessary, as this is a built-in feature in SQL Server. If you say:
>
> CREATE TABLE #nisse (a int NOT NULL)
>
> then the actual name behind the scenes will be something much longer,
>   and no other connections will be able to see this instance of #nisse.

Comment: **Thank you so much**

Comment: @Khalid, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.